# Coroutine usages for asynchronous programming in C++

Tags: asynchronous, future, coroutine, c++20, c++-coroutine

I decided to immerse into C++ coroutines, have read some articles and watched a lot of videos. It is said that coroutines are useful for asynchronous programming. As an example it is usual demonstrated similar examples.
Let's look to one of them: [James McNellis "Introduction to C++ Coroutines" from CppCon2016 (Timing 1:40 - 6:00)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTqHjjm86Bw&t=100s).

Imagine that we want to establish TCP connection and get data from TCP connection:

```
int64_t tcp_reader(int64_t total) {
  std::array<char, 4096> buffer;
  tcp::connection the_connection = tcp::connect("127.0.0.1", 1337);
  int64_t remaining = total;
  for (;;) {
    int64_t bytes_read = the_connection.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size()).get();
    remaining -= bytes_read;
    if (remaining <= 0 || bytes_read == 0) { return remaining); }
  }
}
```

It is not asynchronous, let's imagine that connect() and read() functions already asynchronous(returns std::future) and re-write the function in asynchronous way(too much typing, inserted a picture instead):
[image: Snapshot of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTqHjjm86Bw&t=1695s]

Hmmmmm. Looks crazy, let's rewrite it with coroutines:

```
// std::future instead of just int
std::future<int64_t> tcp_reader(int64_t total) {
  std::array<char, 4096> buffer;
  // tcp::connect returns std::future. Added co_await
  tcp::connection the_connection = co_await tcp::connect("127.0.0.1", 1337);
  int64_t remaining = total;
  for (;;) {
    // tcp::connect::read returns std::future. Added co_await
    int64_t bytes_read = co_await the_connection.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size()).get();
    remaining -= bytes_read;
    if (remaining <= 0 || bytes_read == 0) { return remaining); }
  }
}
```

I do not understand why we complicate it so much. I would just rewrite initial code like this:

```
int64_t tcp_reader(int64_t total) {
  std::array<char, 4096> buffer;
  // tcp::connect returns std::future. Add get();
  tcp::connection the_connection = tcp::connect("127.0.0.1", 1337).get();
  int64_t remaining = total;
  for (;;) {
    // tcp::connect::read returns std::future. Add get();
    int64_t bytes_read = the_connection.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size()).get();
    remaining -= bytes_read;
    if (remaining <= 0 || bytes_read == 0) { return remaining); }
  }
}
std::future<int64_t> async_tcp_reader(int64_t total) {
  return std::async([total]{ tcp_reader(total); });
}
```

Simple and straightforward, isn't it?

I also looked to await/async examples in other languages(Python/JS), there are similar usages.

**Is there are any advantages of using coroutines, comparably to my code in this example?**

**How coroutines can improve my asynchronous code? If you know, please, provide some examples that can illustrate the power of coroutines in async programming**

Comment: The last exemple code is not assynchronous. It is blocking on future::get() function calls. With the coroutine one, if `read` or `connect` is not ready, the co_await expression can resume another coroutine.

Comment: @Oliv, apologies, it was invalid code, I forgotten to add std::async call

Comment: @Oliv, I do not get the point. "If `read` or `connect` is not ready, the `co_await` can resume another coroutine". In my example "without coroutine", if they are not ready, on the caller side I also can call another function or coroutine.

Comment: OK so the difference between the 2 cases is how executions will be managed at low level. With the async, you may get as many threads as there are tcp_readers, and the program execution is going to suffer of the too numerous cpu context switches. But it depends on how async is implemented. With coroutine you can  have more control on how are spawned your tcp_readers and threads. But for this to be possible `read` should be non blocking or you `the_connection` should be "pollable"

Comment: @Oliv, Scott Meyers in Effective modern C++ recommends to use std::future instead of std::thread, to avoid "over-subscription and out of threads". He offer to shift problems on library implementer. Anyway, it is not matter which approach is used (coroutines or non-coroutine), there will be created an asynchronous std::future for each tcp_reader. With coroutine approach, it have to be created implicitly via std::async in promise_type::get_return_object. With non-coroutine approach it must be created explicitly(as in async_tcp_reader function). Do not feel any difference :(

Comment: Probably because there are no difference in this case at code level. Maybe you should try to code a functioning coroutine code: Consider the case where `the_connection` has a member `ready` that return true if there are data on the stream. Then you create something like 1000 tcp_reader connection and you want to resume them on a thread when data is available. And consider you only have a pool of 8 threads.